# Looping using jquery's .each

Tags: jquery, truncate, each

I have a string of dates in which I wish to truncate at the first comma.
e.g., I would like:

- Today, July 9, 2014
- Tomorrow, July 10, 2014
- July 11, 2014

To Display:

- Today
- Tomorrow
- July 11

Using:

```
var longDay = $('.daily_forecast').text(); 
var shortDay = jQuery.trim(longDay).substring(0, 12).split(',').slice(0, -1);
$('.daily_forecast').replaceWith('<span>' + shortDay + '</span>');
```

will properly truncate the content, however, all results are returning "Today".

I believe I need to loop through the elements using .each but am having difficulty doing so.

Thank you.

Comment: You are correct that you need to loop.  Please include the code you've tried that did not work.

Comment: Please post the HTML you're using.

Comment: James Montagne & j08691, thanks much for your interest. I ended up using Barmar's code which works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a function to `.html()`. It will be called on each element that matches the selector, and receive the old contents as a parameter. It can then return the replacement.

```
$('.daily_forecast').html(function(index, longDay) {
    var shortDay = jQuery.trim(longDay).substring(0, 12).split(',').slice(0, -1);
    return '<span>' + shortDay + '</span>';
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/9FPm2/6/)

If the original elements contain HTML rather than plain text, and you need to remove all the markup before replacing it, you'll need to use `.each` explicitly:

```
$('.daily_forecast').each(function() {
    var longDay = $(this).text();
    var shortDay = jQuery.trim(longDay).substring(0, 12).split(',').slice(0, -1);
    $(this).html('<span>' + shortDay + '</span>');
});
```

You probably don't want to use `.replaceWith`, as this removes the entire `.daily_forecast` element. Use `.html()` to replace its contents.

Comment: No, it operates on each matching element independently. There's an implicit `.each()` being done automatically by jQuery.

Comment: A slight difference here is that the original code was reading `text` and not `html`.  It is impossible to say if this is an important distinction as the question did not include the relevant html.  Similarly, the `replaceWith` would replace the element whereas this would insert a span into the element.

Answer (score 0):

using regEx

```
$('.daily_forecast').html(function(index, longDay) {
    var shortDay = jQuery.trim(longDay).match(/[\w\s]+(?=,)/)[0]
    return '<span>' + shortDay + '</span>';
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YDkdP/1/)